# How to access svn in a local area network

Tags: svn

I have installed subversion in my PC (Fedora 14), and I can access the repositories in the svn from my local PC without any problem, but I can't access the svn from another PC in the local network. please assist me...

Comment: Not a programming question, more appropriate for unix/linux/superuser.

Comment: But hint: can you ping the host? Can you connect to another port on the host? Check the firewall on the server, it is probably blocking the port. Disable your firewall/antivirus and see if it works. If that fixes it, re-enable and configure properly.

Comment: yes I can ping the host from another PC

Comment: if other PCs can ping you, check your firewall, if you set on HTTPS add this port to call from another PCs.

Comment: >@Ali: I have opened the port for the apache server and then I is working. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an svn server on the target machine, perhaps svnserve with SASL or even (if you trust your local network users and your local network is secure) without. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html